# Найти минимальную цену min

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

необходимо получить минимальное значение цены (Price), знаю о существовании min, но тут есть проблема, цены в разных array, как в таком случить минимальное число Price и возможно или это...

```
  <?php foreach ($doctor['clinics'] as $clinic) { ?>
       <?php  var_dump($clinic); ?> 
   <?php } ?>

array(4) {
["clinic_id"]=> string(2) "26"
["name"]=> string(31)
"Тестовая клиника"
["href"]=> string(48) "https://site.com/clinic/sdasdasdasdasdasdasdd"
["doctor_clinic_offer"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> array(4) {
        ["doctor_category_name"]=> string(20) "Аллерголог"
        ["price"]=> string(9) "77 грн"
        ["special"]=> bool(false)
        ["special_percentage"]=> bool(false)
    }
    [1]=> array(4) {
        ["doctor_category_name"]=> string(18) "Гинеколог"
        ["price"]=> string(12) "8 000 грн"
        ["special"]=> bool(false)
        ["special_percentage"]=> bool(false) 
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: array_column($clinic['doctor_clinic_offer'], 'price') - вернет массив цен. Превращайте каждое в число и вот тут то min сработает

Comment: Спасибо большое, но только так получается объединить цены одной клиники...

Comment: По аналогии соберите из остальных. Если вам надо одну цифру, массивы можно объединить

Comment: $clinics_price_array = array_merge($doctor['clinics'], $clinic);
$price_array = array_column($clinics_price_array, 'price');              При <?php var_dump($price_array); ?> получаю array(0) { }